# How to handle skewed binary target variables?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, unbalanced-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Supervised learning with “rare” events, when rarity is due to the large number of counter-factual events](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9398/supervised-learning-with-rare-events-when-rarity-is-due-to-the-large-number-o)

I am trying to predict diabetes using the [BRFSS dataset](http://www.cdc.gov/brfss/) by using a supervised learning classification model. But I see that the target variable which is having diabetes or not is skewed. That is 90% of the records are non-diabetic and only 10% of the records are diabetic. How do I handle the skewness in the target variable?

Comment: Why do you perceive "skewness" as a problem that needs correction?

Comment: This question sounds rather similar (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9398/supervised-learning-with-rare-events-when-rarity-is-due-to-the-large-number-of) and Dikran gave a good answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

When your data is skewed you may:

- use specific error metrics like [precision, recall, F-score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)
- trade of between precision and recall accordingly:

  - want to predict diabetes with confidence => adjust for higher precision, lower recall
  - want to avoid missing too many diabetes cases => adjust for lower precision, higher recall
  - (for example, in logistic regression, by adjusting the separating threshold)
- use [F-score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#F-measure)  to find a good balance between precision and recall, that maximizes both as much as possible